# Address field tokens and country display

Tags: views, tokens, entities

I have some user profiles with address fields attached. I created a view of these profiles, with the country as a contextual filter. I'm showing a summary of the results in one of my Views displays, so I can show the countries represented in my data set, with the number of matches for each:
US (12)
CA (6)
DE (3)
and so forth.
I'd prefer to be able to show these as country names rather than 2-letter codes (though the 2-letter code is useful for linking to another part of my view...)

Is there a way to get Views to output the country names in this scenario?
It does just fine when displaying them in fields or full content modes, but not in the result summary.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The addressfield_tokens module extends the addressfield module by adding full token support. It also adds some convenient addressfield formatters and provides a webform addressfield integration.

[Addressfield Token Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_tokens)